# Pyinstaller is not recognized even though its installed

Tags: python, cmd, pip, pyinstaller

I tried to modify the PATH environment and upgrade pip,but it doesn't work

[image: It says pyinstaller is aready installed]

[image: As shown pyinstaller is not beaing reced]

Answer (score 0):

Try updating pip.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```